# Saving the content of div in a charfield model Django

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE inline editor and it changes the conetents of a particular div. I am looking for a way to store those changes in a Django model once a button is pressed.

Comment: Please share your code that you have in place for the view/form

Answer (score 1):

Once you try a 'ckeditor' it's a simmular like tinyMCE and it's easy to use.

just install  **PIP INSTALL ckeditor**

setting.py  ---> installed app in 'ckeditor'

models.py ---> from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

content = RichTextField()

Comment: Problem is that the CKEditor inline editor config doesn't seem to be there for django?